# What are common methods to remove discretization on experimental measures?

Tags: experimental-physics, computational-physics, discrete, data-analysis

I have some experimental data, and since the measurements are digital, the data is discretized/quantized/rounded/truncated.

I need to know if there are general methods, or common methods, to "smooth" the data, remove the discretization, or identify what type of distortion it has (rounding is not the same as truncation or quantization)

I can invent some things, like assuming that data is truncated, and doing interpolations, or using regression to smooth the data, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel and make novice mistakes.

I guess that this is a common problem with measurements, so there must be a set of techniques generally used on experimental physics. Where should I look for them?

Comment: In many (most, I think) cases the answer is you *don't* do anything like that. Really. You analyze the data that you have with an understanding of how the measurement apparatus works.

Comment: I agree with @dmckee unless you can give a specific example or reason explaining why you think you need to "smooth" your data.

Comment: @dmckee; DanielSank I need to calculate derivatives, and use classification algorithms. For example, a part of the curve should be linear, and a wavelet transform should give zero coefficients, but the discretization creates large values for non existent derivatives, or zero derivatives where it should be a slope in the curve. So I need to smooth the data without introducing bias.

Comment: So the real question is what? You want to know specifically how to get derivatives, you want to know how to wavelet transform experimental data, or something else?

Comment: *"So I need to smooth the data without introducing bias"* This is an example of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you need *not* to massage the data and pretend it is something it isn't, it *is* to chose an analysis method that deals gracefully with the limits of the data set: do an appropriate global fit and work from the parameters of the fit, or transform to Fourier space and work there. But no one can suggest the right method without knowing what you problem is.

Comment: For example: (0.1; 0.2; 0.3 ... 0.9; 1.0)  should vary as 0.1, but if it is rounded, it becomes (0.0; 0.0; ... 1.0; 1.0) and the derivative is zero everywhere except at the jumps.

Comment: @ DanielSank the question is "what is the set of techniques commonly used to deal with this common experimental problem". I need a book, the name of a branch of mathematics, or some phrase like "techniques for  curation of digital data" which I can search on google. I need directions.

Comment: @dmckee Im not asking for "the right method", but "what set of methods deal with this kind of problem". There should be entire books dedicated to it.

Comment: @zexot, there are methods used to deal with that- do you have access to a professional statistician? in a previous lifetime, when I encountered that same problem, we had a stats person on the staff I could discuss the problem with but unfortunately I cannot remember what the tool was we used to deal with the issue.

Comment: @zexot, see "quantization error" on wikipedia for a start

Comment: @zexot At first, if you want to be able to recover periodic signal normally, then apparatus sampling frequency should be at least twice as large as your signal frequency. Otherwise, no interpolations will help you to restore original signal.